# How to start autorun programs early?

Tags: windows-10, autostart

We have software that we want to run very early in the login process. The software modifies or hides some elements of the user's desktop, and the user should never see the unmodified desktop.

Now, on Windows 7, just starting the software via auto start works well; the software is already active when the desktop is shown.

For Windows 10 though, the software is started a few seconds after the desktop is initially shown, so it is too late for our purposes.

Is there a way to start the software earlier or delay the desktop?

P.S.: We are doing kiosk-like embedded machines, so we really want to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685960/whats-the-order-of-windows-startup), your best bet is to run the programme as a service. One option is to use the [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/). The relevant bits from the answer:

Source: [Understanding the Startup Process - Windows 7 Tutorial](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/understanding-the-startup-process.html)

> The normal startup sequence for Windows 7 is:
>
> 1. Power-on self test (POST) phase
> 2. Initial startup phase
> 3. Windows Boot Manager phase
> 4. Windows Boot Loader phase
> 5. Kernel loading phase
> 6. Logon phase
>
> [image: a high-level overview of the different paths startup can take]
>
> **Kernel Loading Phase**   The Windows Boot Loader is responsible for loading the Windows kernel (`Ntoskrnl.exe`) and the HAL into memory.
>   Together, the kernel and the HAL initialize a group of software
>   features that are called the Windows executive. The Windows executive
>   processes the configuration information stored in the registry in
>   `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet` and starts services and drivers. The
>   following sections provide more detail about the kernel loading phase.
>
> **Logon Phase**
>
> The Windows subsystem starts `Winlogon.exe`, a system service that
>   enables you to log on and log off. `Winlogon.exe` then does the
>   following:
>
> - Starts the Services subsystem (`Services.exe`), also known as the SCM. The SCM initializes services that the registry entry Start
>     designates as Autoload in the registry subkey
>     `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Servicename`.
> - Starts the Local Security Authority (LSA) process (`Lsass.exe`).
> - Parses the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> key combination at the Begin Logon prompt (if the computer is part of an
>     AD DS domain).
>
> The logon user interface (LogonUI) feature and the credential provider
>   (which can be the standard credential provider or a third-party
>   credential provider) collect the user name and password (or other
>   credentials) and pass this information securely to the LSA for
>   authentication. If the user supplied valid credentials, access is
>   granted by using either the default Kerberos V 5 authentication
>   protocol or Windows NT LAN Manager (NTLM).
>
> Winlogon initializes security and authentication features while PnP
>   initializes auto-load services and drivers. After the user logs on,
>   the control set referenced by the registry entry `LastKnownGood`
>   (located in `HKLM\SYSTEM\Select`) is updated with the contents in the
>   `CurrentControlSet` subkey. By default, Winlogon then starts
>   `Userinit.exe` and the Windows Explorer shell. Userinit may then start
>   other processes, including:
>
> - **Group Policy settings take effect** Group Policy settings that apply to the user and computer take effect.
> - **Startup programs run** When not overridden by Group Policy settings, Windows starts logon scripts, startup programs, and services
>     referenced in the following registry subkeys and file system folders:
>
>   ```
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Runonce
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Run
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
>   SystemDrive\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
>   SystemDrive\Documents and Settings\username\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
>   ```
>
> Several applications might be configured to start by default after you
>   install Windows, including Windows Defender. Computer manufacturers or
>   IT departments might configure other startup applications.
>
> Windows startup is not complete until a user successfully logs on to
>   the computer. If startup fails during the logon phase, you have a
>   problem with a service or application configured to start
>   automatically.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.